# Function for downloading file executing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript function for downloading file from a `textarea` and saving it as JSON, XML or a CSV file.

I have it on my credit card numbers generator. However the downloading function gets executed as many times as I generated new numbers. For example I if I generate numbers five times, it downloads 5 files of the same set of numbers.

How can I fix it? I don't know javascript very much and I copied the download function from the internet.

By the way, if I didn't save 'data.file_format' to the variable it would download files with the previous file formats picked.
Here is link to the web app where it downloads like this:
http://themm1.pythonanywhere.com/advanced/

```js
$('#file_generator').on('submit', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      brand: $('#brand').val(),
      count: $('#count').val(),
      data_format: $('#data_format').val()
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/file_generator'
  }).done(function(data) {
    textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')
    if (data.file_format == 'csv' || data.file_format == 'xml') {
      textarea.value = data.file;
    } else {
      textarea.value = JSON.stringify(data.file, null, 2);
    }
    format = data.file_format
  });

  $('#download').on('click', function() {
    console.log(format)
    var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    text = text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');
    var blob = new Blob([text], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    });
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.download = `creditnumbers.${format}`;
    anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've nested the `click` event handler for `#download` inside the `submit` event for the form. Due to this, every time you generate a number, another click handler is added to the button which in turn creates and downloads another instance of the file. To fix the problem, separate the event handlers.

Also note that you can simplify the logic by using jQuery methods - you've already included it in the page, so you may as well use it!

```js
let $textarea = $('#textarea');

$('#file_generator').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    data: {
      brand: $('#brand').val(),
      count: $('#count').val(),
      data_format: $('#data_format').val()
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/file_generator'
  }).done(function(data) {
    if (data.file_format === 'csv' || data.file_format === 'xml') {
      $textarea.val(data.file);
    } else {
      $textarea.val(JSON.stringify(data.file, null, 2));
    }
  });
});

$('#download').on('click', function() {
  var text = $textarea.val().replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');
  var blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
  $(`<a download="creditnumbers.${$('#data_format').val()}" href="${window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)}" target="_blank" style="display: none;">`).appendTo(document.body)[0].click().remove();
});
```